# How to force users to use specific custom template for meeting workspaces?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar, workspace, user-permissions

I have a calendar on a SharePoint 2010 site and I have created a custom site template based on the standard meeting workspace. I'd like to force users to only be able to use my custom template.

One option is to add `Hidden="TRUE"` in webtemp.xml for all other meeting workspace templates - this will leave mine as the only option. This, however, works on the farm level and I'd like to keep the templates available for other web applications. If I can do this on a web application or lower level it will do the trick.

Even better solution - if I can make the new event dialogue skip the step altogether and use my template without asking.

Background:
My custom template only contains security customizations, no UI or content changes. I want to impose it as I have requirements for the permissions of the meeting workspaces which are different from the parent site - so inheritance has to be broken. But I can't think of another way to supply default permissions other than by using a site template for the workspace.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site Settings > Look and Feel > Page Layouts and Site Templates

choose the site templates you want to be used in the site, this can inherit all the way down the site collection or you can start in a subweb.

Comment: Welcome to SO Robert, you sure started your career with a nice contribution ;-)

The solution works, apart from one detail that I didn't mention in the original question :-) When creating a meeting workspace, users have the option to inherit permissions from the parent site - which defeats most of the benefit of having just one choice for the template. Any ideas how to get around that?